# Ignore gitignore rules

Tags: gitignore

Is there any way to ignore gitignore rules but still check in the .gitignore file? Or maybe we should use a different implementation?

This is not a question about how to apply gitignore rules or "why my rule doesn't work correctly".

We are trying to create templates for our users, which will include 1) a folder that initially exists but will be automatically updated 2) a .gitignore file that has some rules. There is also some logic that copies the whole template folder to the users machine, including both the files mentioned above.

We want to check in the .gitignore file, but we don't want the rules to be applied to our own repo.

The template folder would look like this:

-template
    -generated
        -a.file
-.gitignore

The .gitignore looks something like:

```
...

**/generated
...
```

We want the user to ignore their changes to 'a.file' but we don't want to ignore it for ourselves.

Is there a good way to just ignore the rules, or the better practice is to use a different implementation?

(Apologize if the description is terriblly hard to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could comment out the rules in your repo. Then, on the user's machine, your script could uncomment these lines.

Otherwise, it is possible to check in files that are in your git-ignore file, you just have to be specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

From GIT, they provide a solution to overcome such issues

You can also define personal ignore patterns for a particular repository in a special file at .git/info/exclude. These are not versioned, and not distributed with your repository, so it's an appropriate place to include patterns that will likely only benefit you.

I have never come across any feature where you can ignore the rules or exclude after adding them .gitignore, just you can have changes limited to your repository  by maintaining .git/info/exclude file

Maybe this link would be helpful https://gist.github.com/hieblmedia/9318457
and you can maintain rules specific to your repo in .git/info/exclude.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to:

- ignore a.file (adding that rule in .gitignore)
- but force adding changes when you are in your repository (`git add -f a.file` would still add changes, even if the file is ignored)